# Stanford Parser version 3.8.0

Tags: parsing, stanford-nlp

Dears.
I downloaded Stanford Parser version 3.8.0 from https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml#Download. However,  I do not know how to install it on Microsoft Windows Operating System 8.1. whenever i click on a file, it says "How do you want to open this type of file?"and the message asks me to choose an app. Would you please help me in this regard.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have Java installed on your machine. Then you can simply double-click on *lexparser-gui.bat*, which opens a terminal and displays a GUI where you can start your parsing.

Comment: Can you please send me the link for the suitable java player? Thank you

Comment: You can download Java here: [Java download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your substantial help. Yeah, now it works well especially when I load a file. However, when I paste a text into the textbox, the parse button is still INACTIVE. Can you help?

Comment: You have to load a Parser first. Do so by clicking on **Load Parser** and choose the model file **stanford-parser-3.8.0-models.jar** (in the top directory of your Parser distribution). Then you have to choose an actual parser. I suggest you use **englishPCFG.ser.gz**, at least to begin with. After the parser has loaded you are good to go!